# Modal prop onDismiss on Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was looking to an alternative to the onDismiss prop on Modal, which itsnt supported on Android. I need to trigger a function as soon as it fully closes

```
    <CustomModal
      title={titleModal}
      openModal={openModal}
      onDismiss={this.setValueWhenClosed}
      closeOutside
    >
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best choice will be using [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal) then you can use **onModalHide** porps to understand if modal has been hidden.

Comment: isnt it onRequestClose triggered just when we press the back button on android?  "The onRequestClose callback is called when the user taps the hardware back button on Android or the menu button on Apple TV"

Comment: @FedericoDiaz I just edited my answer. Hope this can fit your need. Good luck ;-)